# Change the format of date picker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am building an android application where a user select the date using date picker tool.

The format of the date I get is 20 12 2014 and I need the format 20 December 2014.

Here is my code :

```
        public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceSateate) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen

       //tdate.setText((month));

        tdate.setText(day + "  " + (month + 1) + "  " + year);
        //date = tdate.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (mYear != year || mMonth != monthOfYear || mDay != dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateSpinners();

            //HERE
            reorderPickers(new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths());

            notifyDateChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to use updateDate function. colud you please help as i am new to android